# How to create a file in memory in Windows Server?

Tags: windows, memory, windows-server-2008, cache

How can I store and have access to a file in memory in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard? I would like to have quick access to a database. Since SQLite stores database in file I would like to store this file in memory.

Comment: Use a software RAMDrive solution then make that storage location available to the network.

Comment: When I attach SQLite to database file, stored on disk, it is not loaded in RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take [a look](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), HTH:

> An SQLite database is normally stored in a single ordinary disk file.
>   However, in certain circumstances, the database might be stored in
>   memory.
>
> The most common way to force an SQLite database to exist purely in
>   memory is to open the database using the special filename ":memory:".
>   In other words, instead of passing the name of a real disk file into
>   one of the sqlite3_open(), sqlite3_open16(), or sqlite3_open_v2()
>   functions, pass in the string ":memory:". For example:

```
rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
```